# How to remove itself from its parent WITHOUT error in DesignMode

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I'm tried to make a control that will kill itself when added to a form.
Actually what I want to do is make a control that will ask for password before added to a form, and remove itself if the password is wrong...
Anything work great, it really will remove itself from the parent form, but it will show a error message too:
"'child' is not a child control of this parent."

Here the code:

```
Public Class SuicideCustomButton
    Inherits Button

    Protected Overrides Sub InitLayout()
        If DesignMode Then
            Me.Parent.Controls.Remove(Me)
            'ALWAYS SHOW ERROR HERE
        Else
            Me.Parent.Controls.Remove(Me)
            'NO ERROR SHOWED HERE
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

How can I get rid of that error message?

Comment: Erm, you're removing the control in both cases. Is that why it's showing an error message? Because the control has already been removed before you show the error?

Comment: @CodyGray nope... that is not the reason why it show a error message. I remove the control in both cases to show that the code "Me.Parent.Controls.Remove(Me)" work great without error in running mode but not in designmode...

Comment: @CodyGray I think the reason it show the error msg is because there's other event raised after InitLayout()... But I don't know which event is it...

Comment: I am not proficient in Visual Basic but I find suspicious the idea to remove a control in design mode right after its creation (it's meant to be persistent): Why not prevent its creation unless the password is OK (I believe there should be a way to intercept control creation in design time and abort it if need be).

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can hide your control from being visible in ToolBox

```
<System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class SuicideCustomButton
    Inherits Button

    ...

End Class
```

**Update:**

This is a new version it's a smart stuff that ask you for a password in design mode and if you want to create an instance by code (without designer) you should pass a password to constructor :

```
Public Class SuicideCustomButton
    Inherits Button

    Dim KillMeOut As Boolean = False
    Private _Pass As String
    Public Property Pass() As String
        Get
            Return _Pass
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Pass = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub OnLocationChanged(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnLocationChanged(e)
        '                                                                                                                 In Design mode this is required
        If DesignMode AndAlso KillMeOut AndAlso Me.Parent IsNot Nothing AndAlso Me.Parent.Controls.Contains(Me) Then
            Me.Parent.Controls.Remove(Me)
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub InitLayout()
        MyBase.InitLayout()
        If Pass <> "xpass" Then

            If Not DesignMode AndAlso Not KillMeOut AndAlso Me.Parent IsNot Nothing AndAlso Me.Parent.Controls.Contains(Me) Then
                Throw New Exception("You can't add this object in without a password :)")
            Else
                If Not PassInputFrm.Pass Then
                    KillMeOut = True
                Else
                    Pass = "xpass"
                End If
            End If

        End If

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' This will be used in design mode
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Use this constructor in code mode
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub New(ByVal pass As String)
        If Not PassInputFrm.ValidatePass(pass) Then
            KillMeOut = True
        Else
            pass = "xpass"
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

You will need a form for password input so i make one and upload it [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?5zi8khfeq8ac9g1)

Comment: Well, what I want was not this... I want the control show in toolbox, but I don't want it can be created without correct password is entered...

Comment: You want to set password in designer ?

Comment: I wanna to do like this:
* If added in designer mode, then it will ask you password, if correct it will continue, otherwise will delete itself.
* If added by code, I want it will ask password too, but now I don't get the idea how to do this perfectly..
* I want it ask for password only if there's no other of SuicideCustomButton in form

Comment: But man, that's a problem with your code. When it delete itself, it don't show error. However, it will not delete itself completely... Just have a look of form1.designer.vb or the "control listbox" in the form designer and you will understand... Can the code work better?

Comment: To show an error it's simple use a messagebox right before i remove the control, about complete removing i know that it's still in designer but it in form controls so it will not be shown at runtime, anyway your question is weird and i'm the only that spend a time for it... so i hope that you deal with that. Regards